# Dynamically set checkbox label text cause the style issue in checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

In my `jquery mobile(v 1.3.2)` application i just created a checkbox and set checkbox text dynamically using jquery. When set like this the checkbox style is collapsed.

Here's is the sample code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="OptIconsLabels" id="OptIconsLabels" class="custom" data-theme="c" />
<label for="OptIconsLabels"></label>
```

Js:

```
$("#OptToolbarLbl").text("Label");
$('label[for="OptIconsLabels"]').text("Opt Icon");
$("#OptIconsLabels").attr("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Here is the [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oLwwrzLs/)

Note: I tried trigger page create also

```
$(.page).trigger("pagecreate");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the DOM structure after page load then `label` is not getting used as it is but there are some `<span>` get added as a children to display `label` text. That span has `class="ui-btn-text"` which you need to update. See below code -

```
$(document).on("pageshow","#OptionsGeneral", function() {

     $("#OptToolbarLbl").text("Label");
     $('label[for="OptIconsLabels"] span.ui-btn-text').text("Opt Icon");
     $("#OptIconsLabels").attr("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh");
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oLwwrzLs/9/)**

Comment: not able to accept need to wait 2 mins..i have one more doubt the anchor tag button text set dynamically when setting like this the icon are not visible.

Comment: no problem, accept it after 2 mins. You need to inspect DOM what structure it is making after page load, use below links to inspect for firefox and chrome browser. [FIREFOX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM_Inspector/Introduction_to_DOM_Inspector) and [CHROME](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements)

Comment: please share a jsfiddle link

Comment: Since your anchor is a button with plus sign on it, you cannot put text on it. At the max you can add text to anchor's parent div like this http://jsfiddle.net/oLwwrzLs/17/

Comment: thats what it won't get combined for which may need to use some other theme for anchor.

Comment: in my phonegap app i am able to do this using this `$('#mSubmit2').parent().find('span').html("saveBtn");`

Comment: any idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778652/not-able-to-close-the-jt-sage-date-picker-after-pick-date